# Why does JS condition statement not working in a function?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a basic website that allows users to hide/show checkbox when a button is clicked. However, I need to click the button twice to get it to work. Any idea why?

```js
function myFunction() {
  var check_box = document.getElementById('checkbox');
  if (check_box.style.display === "block") {
    check_box.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    check_box.style.display = "block";

  }
}
```

```html
<button id="button" onclick="myFunction()">
Show/Hide Checkbox
</button>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
```

Comment: The initial display value isn't "block" or "none".  Use your debugger to see what the initial value is.

Comment: The `.style` object only shows styles that are directly coded onto the HTML elements. Default styles are not available.

Comment: What Amy said above, therefore when you first click, it will *set it to `block`*

Comment: @Amy what is the default value for input?

Comment: may I suggest you use a CSS class that will use `display: none;` and toggle the class instead of the  inline style

Comment: There is no single default value unless you set it yourself.  Use your debugger to see what the initial value is.

Comment: use `display !== "none"` for if condition .its will validate only element not hidden

Comment: `<input>` elements are "inline", but that will not be made evident by `.style.display`; it will be empty unless the element is explicitly styled in the HTML.